# Jquery Validation Resets page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i'm new to using javascript plugins to validate data in forms and therefore am having problems. Currently,  the first validation works fine and executes the correct jquery, however the second validation for the second section of the form resets the page when valid data is entered.

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/epn63vk3/2/

You can also check out the version with the css fully working at :

```
http://178.62.85.190/index.html
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonToSecondaryDetailsSection").click(function (e) {
        $('#primaryDetailsForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                forenameInput: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                surnameInput: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                emailInput: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            }
        });
        var primaryValid = $('#primaryDetailsForm').valid();
        if (primaryValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#primaryDetailsForm").slideUp("slow");
            $("#secondaryDetailsForm").slideDown("slow");
        } else {

        }
    });

    $("#buttonToCommentsSection").click(function (f) {
        $('#secondaryDetailsForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                telephoneInput: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 11,
                    maxlength: 11
                },
                genderInput: {
                    required: true,
                },
                dobInput: {
                    required: true,
                    dateFormat: true
                }
            }
        });
        var secondaryValid = $('#secondaryDetailsForm').valid();
        if (secondaryValid) {
            f.preventDefault();
            $("#secondaryDetailsForm").slideUp("slow");
            $("#commentsDetailsForm").slideDown("slow");
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Forms :

```
<div id = "sections">
            <div id = "titlePanel">
                <p id = "sectionTitle">
                    Step 1: Your primary details
                </p>
            </div>              
            <form id = "primaryDetailsForm" method = "POST">
                <label for "forenameInput" id = "labels"> First Name </label>
                <br>
                <input id = "forenameInput" name = "forenameInput" type = "text" class = "input-block-level">
                <br>
                <label for "surnameInput" id = "label1"> Surname </label>
                <br>
                <input id = "surnameInput" name = "surnameInput" type = "text" class = "input-block-level">
                <br>
                <label for "emailInput" id = "label2"> Email Address:</label>
                <br>
                <input id = "emailInput" name = "emailInput" type = "email" class = "input-block-level">
                <br>
                <div id = "registrationButtonWrapper">
                    <button id = "buttonToSecondaryDetailsSection" class = "btn btn-default"> next > </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id = "Div1">
            <div id =  "Div2">
                <p id = "P1">
                    Step 2: Additional details
                </p>
            </div>
            <form id = "secondaryDetailsForm" method = "POST">
                <label for "telephoneInput" id = "label3"> Telephone Number </label>
                <br>
                <input id = "telephoneInput" name = "telephoneInput" type = "number" class = "input-block-level">
                <br>
                <label for "genderInput" id = "label4"> Gender </label>
                <br>
                <select id = "genderInput" name="genderInput">
                    <option value="male"> Male </option>
                    <option value="female"> Female </option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for "dateOfBirthInput" id = "label5"> Date Of Birth </label>
                <br>
                <input id = "dateOfBirthInput" name = "dobInput" type = "date" class = "input-block-level">
                <br>
                <div id = "Div3">
                    <button id = "buttonToCommentsSection" class = "btn btn-default" > next > </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are adding the validation on each click, you should first check if it was added. Also the date validation looks like its failing. Where is `dateFormat` from? If you use `date` it will work.

Comment: I got dataFormat from a similar post asking how to use date in jquery validation. I solved the problem by removing the validation from the button clicks. Previously, i assumed the validation had to be done on click but i guess that wasnt the case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChrisWaszczuk, exactly correct to remove it from button `click` event.  After all, wherever you copied that code, my own comments are still attached... `// initialize the plugin`; implying that's something you only do once.